# Linker error on TestTargets Xcode

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xcode9

I have started receiving following error suddenly on TestTarget, not sure what has changed

> Showing All Issues
>   ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

I have turned off bitcode already on app build target.
App is building fine and running , this error appears only for testing .

Comment: Is that the exact / complete error ? Check if you are changing the bit code setting in the correct target. Enabling bit code in general is a good thing as it keep app size small. I think for test targets it is ok to disable them (not 100% sure)

Comment: @user1046037 its not showing any setting for test target so i m able to change only for app target , yes thats exact same error

Comment: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=xcode+select+target+build+settings&client=safari&hl=en-sg&prmd=vin&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja-qziyu3WAhVDv5QKHSJKA0UQ_AUIEygC&biw=375&bih=553#imgdii=7X2kOvuheY3KaM:&imgrc=DXiywCAz2z9FtM:

Comment: Did you turn off bitcode on the test target?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I am not able to see any such setting specific to test target